# Ошибка - Function name must be a string in

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, php7, print

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in C:\OpenServer\domains\akto\wp-content\themes\akto\functions.php:230

```
function getReviews(){
    $args = array(
       'orderby'    => 'date',
       'order'      => 'ASC',
       'post_type' => 'reviews'
    );

    $reviews = [];

    foreach ($get_posts($args) as $post) {
        $review = get_fields($post->ID);
        $reviews[] = $review;
    }

    return $reviews;
}

print_r(getReviews());
```

Comment: `$get_posts` у Вас что такое?

Comment: Спасибо. Вы очень помогли)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_posts` - это функция wp , а я ее случайно переменной объявил.